# Return data contained in two different models in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models a User model and a profile model. I am using the user id as the foreign key for the profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    website = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phoneno = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    gender = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='images/avatar/', default='/images/avatar/blank.png')
```

I am using the built in user model by django which contains the fields of username, password etc...

I want to create a serializer wherein I can return the details of both the Profile and User Model. So far I can return the details of the user if I use UserSerializer instead of the ProfileUserCombinedSerializer below.

However I have created ProfileUserCombinedSerializer so that I can combine the values of the two,so far I have the following

```
class UserSeralizer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password',"email","first_name","last_name")


class ProfileUserCombinedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',"user")
```

How do I append the corresponding profile model to the queryset so that the corresponding fields of bio, website ect get serialized so I can view them in the browsable api.

```
class returnProfileDetailsFromUser(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileUserCombinedSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        i = self.kwargs['id']
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.filter(id=i)
        return queryset
```

Now I end up getting the following error:

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `ProfileUserCombinedSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in Django rest framework you must work with related name in models. Rewrite models as:

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True, related_name = 'user_profile')
```

## serializer.py

```
class ProfileUserCombinedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("user","bio",)

class UserSeralizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password',"email","first_name","last_name","user_profile",)
```

Then in your views call UserSeralizer and send ID of user.